# will_paginate returning multiple duplicates

Tags: ruby-on-rails, will-paginate

will_paginate is going nuts.  I asked it to return 12 rows, and it duplicates those 12 12 times on a page, giving me 12 sets of duplicates and a total of 144 rows on a page.

My controller code:

```
  query = "address1 LIKE \"%#{params[:filter]}%\""
  @properties = Property.where(query).group("id").paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 12)
```

At first, the log files show this:

```
Processing by PropertiesController#index as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "filter"=>"Acacia", "commit"=>"Filter"}
  Rendering properties/index.html.erb within layouts/application
  Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (2.2ms)
   (34.7ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) AS count_all, `property`.`id` AS property_id FROM `property` WHERE (address1 LIKE "%Acacia%") GROUP BY `property`.`id`
  Property Load (34.9ms)  SELECT  `property`.* FROM `property` WHERE (address1 LIKE "%Acacia%") GROUP BY `property`.`id` LIMIT 12 OFFSET 0
  Photo Load (34.5ms)  SELECT  `photos`.* FROM `photos` WHERE `photos`.`propid` = 10001 LIMIT 1
  Photo Load (34.8ms)  SELECT  `photos`.* FROM `photos` WHERE `photos`.`propid` = 10002 LIMIT 1
  Photo Load (34.4ms)  SELECT  `photos`.* FROM `photos` WHERE `photos`.`propid` = 10003 LIMIT 1
  Photo Load (34.4ms)  SELECT  `photos`.* FROM `photos` WHERE `photos`.`propid` = 10004 LIMIT 1
  Photo Load (34.5ms)  SELECT  `photos`.* FROM `photos` WHERE `photos`.`propid` = 10005 LIMIT 1
  Photo Load (34.3ms)  SELECT  `photos`.* FROM `photos` WHERE `photos`.`propid` = 10006 LIMIT 1
  Photo Load (34.6ms)  SELECT  `photos`.* FROM `photos` WHERE `photos`.`propid` = 10007 LIMIT 1
  Photo Load (35.7ms)  SELECT  `photos`.* FROM `photos` WHERE `photos`.`propid` = 10008 LIMIT 1
  Photo Load (34.6ms)  SELECT  `photos`.* FROM `photos` WHERE `photos`.`propid` = 10009 LIMIT 1
  Photo Load (34.6ms)  SELECT  `photos`.* FROM `photos` WHERE `photos`.`propid` = 10010 LIMIT 1
  Photo Load (34.6ms)  SELECT  `photos`.* FROM `photos` WHERE `photos`.`propid` = 10011 LIMIT 1
  Photo Load (39.3ms)  SELECT  `photos`.* FROM `photos` WHERE `photos`.`propid` = 10012 LIMIT 1
```

Then it shows this 11 more times:

```
  Rendered collection of properties/_property.html.erb [12 times] (467.1ms)
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  `photos`.* FROM `photos` WHERE `photos`.`propid` = 10001 LIMIT 1  [["propid", 10001], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  `photos`.* FROM `photos` WHERE `photos`.`propid` = 10002 LIMIT 1  [["propid", 10002], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  `photos`.* FROM `photos` WHERE `photos`.`propid` = 10003 LIMIT 1  [["propid", 10003], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  `photos`.* FROM `photos` WHERE `photos`.`propid` = 10004 LIMIT 1  [["propid", 10004], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  `photos`.* FROM `photos` WHERE `photos`.`propid` = 10005 LIMIT 1  [["propid", 10005], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  `photos`.* FROM `photos` WHERE `photos`.`propid` = 10006 LIMIT 1  [["propid", 10006], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  `photos`.* FROM `photos` WHERE `photos`.`propid` = 10007 LIMIT 1  [["propid", 10007], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  `photos`.* FROM `photos` WHERE `photos`.`propid` = 10008 LIMIT 1  [["propid", 10008], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  `photos`.* FROM `photos` WHERE `photos`.`propid` = 10009 LIMIT 1  [["propid", 10009], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  `photos`.* FROM `photos` WHERE `photos`.`propid` = 10010 LIMIT 1  [["propid", 10010], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  `photos`.* FROM `photos` WHERE `photos`.`propid` = 10011 LIMIT 1  [["propid", 10011], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  `photos`.* FROM `photos` WHERE `photos`.`propid` = 10012 LIMIT 1  [["propid", 10012], ["LIMIT", 1]]
```

Any idea what is causing this mass duplication?  I've googled and only found answers to a single item being duplicated at the bottom of one page and the top of another, and that's not the case here.

Thanks!

EDIT: Switched from will_paginate to Kaminari and am still having the same issue.  Kaminari code from the controller:

```
@properties = Property.where(query).page(params[:page]).per(12)
```

View:

```
<% provide(:title, 'All Properties') %>

<%= render "layouts/header" %>

<div class="text-center top-padding-to-miss-navbar">
  <h1>All Properties</h1>
</div>

<div id="pi-filter">
  <%= form_tag '', :method => :get do %>
    <%= text_field('', :filter, :value => params[:filter]) %>
    <%= submit_tag 'Filter' %>
  <% end %>
</div>

<div id="pi-create-new-property-link">
  <%= link_to "Create New Property", property_new_path %>
</div>

<div class="ui-left-margin">
  <%= will_paginate %>
</div>

<div id="ui-padded-sides">
  <ul class="properties">
    <% @properties.each do %>
      <%= render @properties %>
    <% end %>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="ui-left-margin">
  <%= will_paginate %>
</div>
```

Partial used by view:

```
<li>
  <%= link_to property.address1, property %>
  <%= link_to "| Edit" , property_edit_path(property) %>
  <%= link_to "| Delete", property, method: :delete,
      data: { confirm: "Are you sure you want to delete this property?" } %>
</li>
```

Comment: What you show on the page, properites or photos? Because your console log shows that Rails fetches 12 properties, and then set of photos for each property. Can you show your view template?

Comment: @IlyaKonyukhov I am just trying to show properties on the page.  No photos at all.  I don't know why that's coming up in the logs.  I added my view template above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the update. Now it's clear where the problem is.

Here:

```
<% @properties.each do %>
  <%= render @properties %>
<% end %>
```

you're iterating over `@properties`, and on each iteration render a collection of `@properties`. Assuming `@properties` has 12 elements, it gives you 12 times 12 properties = 144.

To fix it just replace that loop with

```
<%= render @properties %>
```

This is a shorthand for `<%= render partial: 'property', collection: @properties %>`. It will render your collection only one time.

See details at https://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#rendering-collections

Comment: Thanks so much @IlyaKonyukhov!  That did the trick.  I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

First, you probably really don't want to be creating a query with string interpolation like you are. If this is an app exposed to the internet, bad guys can inject whatever they want into that query. See the "unsafe" warning here and how to use `?` in your queries: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#pure-string-conditions.

As for what's causing this, I believe it might be coming from using that "group(id)" clause. You aren't aggregating anything around id. So the query should be:

```
@properties = Property.where(query).paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 12)
```

Comment: Thanks Nathan for the heads up on the security risk.

Removing the group(id) didn't help.  In fact, I switched to Kaminari and am using this code: @properties = Property.where(query).page(params[:page]).per(12) and I'm still getting the same issue.